# Output formatted Text in WordPress (ul and li changed to p tag issue)

Tags: wordpress, text-formatting

I am using a readymade theme in which the Job description is not showing Formatted Text.

Below are few lines of WordPress single post code:

```
$job_about_me = html_entity_decode(get_post_meta($post->ID, htmlentities(stripslashes('job-about-me')),true));

$content = $job_about_me;

                        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
                        $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
                        echo wpautop($content);
```

So, the output of this code is as shown below:

```css
.full {
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="full" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
      <p>Shirish</p>
<p>Gururaj</p>
<p>Jay</p>
     </div>
```

I want the output of the code to be in ul and li but not p tags.

In short a Formatted HTML page should be visible.

I tried a lot but need your help.

Comment: It sounds like you need to modify the post meta you've saved in the Admin.

Comment: Hi Mevius, can you give me more details? This is the single post page where the output is fetched!. I am also using tinyMCE for this in the backend.

Comment: I think you need to change the formatting in tinyMCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?

```
echo str_replace(
    array( '<div', '</div>' '<p', '</p>'  ),
    array( '<ul', '</ul>', '<li', '</li>' ),
    wpautop( $content )
);
```

Comment: Hi Marcus, its not only about ul and li, talking about other formatted text, I feel there should be a way to render HTML as shown in Visual Text Editor of TinyMCE.

Comment: I did try to write the way you said and below is the code which i get:
`code`
<div class="full" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
<li>Shirish</li>
<li>Gururaj</li>
<li>Jay</li>
</div>`code`

ul is missing. But it seems to be working.